# client-side validation including unicode character ranges

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, regex, unicode

I got an `asp:Textbox` as well as an `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` on my page. Now I try to validate the input for any character of any culture i.e. the German name `Günter`. Unfortunately instead of the server-sided validation, the client-sided validation fails, because JavaScript is unable to match all culture letters when using `\w` in the regular expression pattern. Using explicit characters works (`^[\wÄÜÖäüö]+$`), but this is no solution, since I have to support ALL letters of ALL cultures.

To be honest I need `\p{L}` in JavaScript. There is a library (XRegExp) that supports this very well. But, how can I force ASP.NET to use this library instead of the default regex functions of JavaScript? I do not want to use an `asp:CustomValidator` and make even more work to do per form I create.

Answer (score 1):

The validation in RegularExpressionValidator is done server side or client side.

When you set EnableClientScript="false" you can use "\p{L}" to validate "Günter"

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbox1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
        ControlToValidate="txtbox1"  
        ValidationExpression="\p{L}+"
        EnableClientScript="false"
        ErrorMessage="Error"
        runat="server" />
```

If EnableClientScript="true", your regular expression must be ECMAScript compliant, otherwise it will fail. The behavior of ECMAScript and canonical regular expressions differs, see [ECMAScript Matching Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ECMAScript).

In other words, to match unicode letters you need to set exact code of each letter or a range between letters similar to a-zA-Z.

Example: to match most of "european" letters from À-ž (see character map tool), use

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
        ControlToValidate="txtbox1"  
        ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u017e]+"
        EnableClientScript="true"
        ErrorMessage="Error"
        runat="server" />
```

Comment: Exactly what I talked about. As you can see in my question I already mentioned everything you just told me. But my problem is I want to hook such Unicode support into the client sided script. I don't want to disable JavaScript validation and I do not want to force the form creator to add specified Unicode ranges by hand. As you can see I answered my question with a way to hook this support into the client sided code, already. It's just not so beautiful. So I'm looking for **better ways** to archive this, hence your answer does not help. However, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Your code requires additional javascript and changes in the Render() method. My code does not require anything, you just specify [a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u017e]+ and that will work.

Comment: So if I have two similar validators for two textboxes (same regex patterns printed **two times** in the pre-last script tag in my HTML output) that should allow any uppercase letters from all **cultures** you really suggest me to use the validation pattern `^[\u01bb\u01c0-\u01c3\u0294\u05d0-\u05ea\u05f0-\u05f2\u0621-\u063a\u0641-\u064a\u066e\u066f\u0671-\u06d3\u06d5\u06ee\u06ef\u06fa-\\u06fc\\u06ff\\u0710\\u0712-\\u072f\\u074d-\\u076d\\u0780-\u07a5\u07b1\u07ca-\u07ea\u0904-\u0939...]+$`? Actually the list is 10 times longer for only uppercase letters, and I got several validators on my page

Comment: So, specify the ranges like `[a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u017e]+` manually is the problem here, because the lists are just too long in my case. This increases my HTML output enormous and brings even more work to people who build forms for the application.

Comment: Your original question was regarding "solution ... to support ALL letters of ALL cultures", thence I suggest to use "[a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u017e]+" to match a-zA-Z and most of "european" letters from À-ž. I do not suggest to use "^[\u01bb\u01c0-\u01c3\u....]" because my idea to set range for all letters together from À-ž. My pattern also does not require any change in Render() and does not change HTML output. If you try my code you'll see that "Günter" is matched on client side.

Comment: So you suggest me to use only a-zA-Z and most of "european" letters from À-ž" when I was literally searching for a solution to match "ALL letters of ALL cultures"? If you still don't get me: I got a name text field and I want to use the validator of ASP.NET (even on client side) to make sure, people can only enter their names in their home language. No matter they write Japanese, Taiwan, Javanese, Polish, or what ever they speak. And of course, I do not want to allow names like `T|—|15`. If you still believe your answer is correct, simply ignore this question for now. ...

Comment: It wasn't obvious for me regarding all languages. In this case you're right regarding having multiple ranges. I think you know that such validation allows "mixed" letters, e.g. "Aki秋".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got a solution that is not very elegant, but it works.

As first, link to a JavaScript file in your HTML that contains this:

```
var u = {
Pi: "\\u00ab\\u2018\\u201b\\u201c\\u201f\\u2039\\u2e02\\u2e04\\u2e09\\u2e0c\\u2e1c",
Sk: "\\u005e\\u0060\\u00a8\\u00af\\u00b4\\u00b8\\u02c2-\\u02c5\\u02d2-\\u02df\\u02e5-\\u02ed\\u02ef-\\u02ff\\u0374\\u0375\\u0384\\u0385\\u1fbd\\u1fbf-\\u1fc1\\u1fcd-\\u1fcf\\u1fdd-\\u1fdf\\u1fed-\\u1fef\\u1ffd\\u1ffe\\u309b\\u309c\\ua700-\\ua716\\ua720\\ua721\\uff3e\\uff40\\uffe3",
Sm: "\\u002b\\u003c-\\u003e\\u007c\\u007e\\u00ac\\u00b1\\u00d7\\u00f7\\u03f6\\u2044\\u2052\\u207a-\\u207c\\u208a-\\u208c\\u2140-\\u2144\\u214b\\u2190-\\u2194\\u219a\\u219b\\u21a0\\u21a3\\u21a6\\u21ae\\u21ce\\u21cf\\u21d2\\u21d4\\u21f4-\\u22ff\\u2308-\\u230b\\u2320\\u2321\\u237c\\u239b-\\u23b3\\u23dc-\\u23e1\\u25b7\\u25c1\\u25f8-\\u25ff\\u266f\\u27c0-\\u27c4\\u27c7-\\u27ca\\u27d0-\\u27e5\\u27f0-\\u27ff\\u2900-\\u2982\\u2999-\\u29d7\\u29dc-\\u29fb\\u29fe-\\u2aff\\ufb29\\ufe62\\ufe64-\\ufe66\\uff0b\\uff1c-\\uff1e\\uff5c\\uff5e\\uffe2\\uffe9-\\uffec",
So: "\\u00a6\\u00a7\\u00a9\\u00ae\\u00b0\\u00b6\\u0482\\u060e\\u060f\\u06e9\\u06fd\\u06fe\\u07f6\\u09fa\\u0b70\\u0bf3-\\u0bf8\\u0bfa\\u0cf1\\u0cf2\\u0f01-\\u0f03\\u0f13-\\u0f17\\u0f1a-\\u0f1f\\u0f34\\u0f36\\u0f38\\u0fbe-\\u0fc5\\u0fc7-\\u0fcc\\u0fcf\\u1360\\u1390-\\u1399\\u1940\\u19e0-\\u19ff\\u1b61-\\u1b6a\\u1b74-\\u1b7c\\u2100\\u2101\\u2103-\\u2106\\u2108\\u2109\\u2114\\u2116-\\u2118\\u211e-\\u2123\\u2125\\u2127\\u2129\\u212e\\u213a\\u213b\\u214a\\u214c\\u214d\\u2195-\\u2199\\u219c-\\u219f\\u21a1\\u21a2\\u21a4\\u21a5\\u21a7-\\u21ad\\u21af-\\u21cd\\u21d0\\u21d1\\u21d3\\u21d5-\\u21f3\\u2300-\\u2307\\u230c-\\u231f\\u2322-\\u2328\\u232b-\\u237b\\u237d-\\u239a\\u23b4-\\u23db\\u23e2-\\u23e7\\u2400-\\u2426\\u2440-\\u244a\\u249c-\\u24e9\\u2500-\\u25b6\\u25b8-\\u25c0\\u25c2-\\u25f7\\u2600-\\u266e\\u2670-\\u269c\\u26a0-\\u26b2\\u2701-\\u2704\\u2706-\\u2709\\u270c-\\u2727\\u2729-\\u274b\\u274d\\u274f-\\u2752\\u2756\\u2758-\\u275e\\u2761-\\u2767\\u2794\\u2798-\\u27af\\u27b1-\\u27be\\u2800-\\u28ff\\u2b00-\\u2b1a\\u2b20-\\u2b23\\u2ce5-\\u2cea\\u2e80-\\u2e99\\u2e9b-\\u2ef3\\u2f00-\\u2fd5\\u2ff0-\\u2ffb\\u3004\\u3012\\u3013\\u3020\\u3036\\u3037\\u303e\\u303f\\u3190\\u3191\\u3196-\\u319f\\u31c0-\\u31cf\\u3200-\\u321e\\u322a-\\u3243\\u3250\\u3260-\\u327f\\u328a-\\u32b0\\u32c0-\\u32fe\\u3300-\\u33ff\\u4dc0-\\u4dff\\ua490-\\ua4c6\\ua828-\\ua82b\\ufdfd\\uffe4\\uffe8\\uffed\\uffee\\ufffc\\ufffd",
Po: "\\u0021-\\u0023\\u0025-\\u0027\\u002a\\u002c\\u002e\\u002f\\u003a\\u003b\\u003f\\u0040\\u005c\\u00a1\\u00b7\\u00bf\\u037e\\u0387\\u055a-\\u055f\\u0589\\u05be\\u05c0\\u05c3\\u05c6\\u05f3\\u05f4\\u060c\\u060d\\u061b\\u061e\\u061f\\u066a-\\u066d\\u06d4\\u0700-\\u070d\\u07f7-\\u07f9\\u0964\\u0965\\u0970\\u0df4\\u0e4f\\u0e5a\\u0e5b\\u0f04-\\u0f12\\u0f85\\u0fd0\\u0fd1\\u104a-\\u104f\\u10fb\\u1361-\\u1368\\u166d\\u166e\\u16eb-\\u16ed\\u1735\\u1736\\u17d4-\\u17d6\\u17d8-\\u17da\\u1800-\\u1805\\u1807-\\u180a\\u1944\\u1945\\u19de\\u19df\\u1a1e\\u1a1f\\u1b5a-\\u1b60\\u2016\\u2017\\u2020-\\u2027\\u2030-\\u2038\\u203b-\\u203e\\u2041-\\u2043\\u2047-\\u2051\\u2053\\u2055-\\u205e\\u2cf9-\\u2cfc\\u2cfe\\u2cff\\u2e00\\u2e01\\u2e06-\\u2e08\\u2e0b\\u2e0e-\\u2e16\\u3001-\\u3003\\u303d\\u30fb\\ua874-\\ua877\\ufe10-\\ufe16\\ufe19\\ufe30\\ufe45\\ufe46\\ufe49-\\ufe4c\\ufe50-\\ufe52\\ufe54-\\ufe57\\ufe5f-\\ufe61\\ufe68\\ufe6a\\ufe6b\\uff01-\\uff03\\uff05-\\uff07\\uff0a\\uff0c\\uff0e\\uff0f\\uff1a\\uff1b\\uff1f\\uff20\\uff3c\\uff61\\uff64\\uff65",
Mn: "\\u0300-\\u036f\\u0483-\\u0486\\u0591-\\u05bd\\u05bf\\u05c1\\u05c2\\u05c4\\u05c5\\u05c7\\u0610-\\u0615\\u064b-\\u065e\\u0670\\u06d6-\\u06dc\\u06df-\\u06e4\\u06e7\\u06e8\\u06ea-\\u06ed\\u0711\\u0730-\\u074a\\u07a6-\\u07b0\\u07eb-\\u07f3\\u0901\\u0902\\u093c\\u0941-\\u0948\\u094d\\u0951-\\u0954\\u0962\\u0963\\u0981\\u09bc\\u09c1-\\u09c4\\u09cd\\u09e2\\u09e3\\u0a01\\u0a02\\u0a3c\\u0a41\\u0a42\\u0a47\\u0a48\\u0a4b-\\u0a4d\\u0a70\\u0a71\\u0a81\\u0a82\\u0abc\\u0ac1-\\u0ac5\\u0ac7\\u0ac8\\u0acd\\u0ae2\\u0ae3\\u0b01\\u0b3c\\u0b3f\\u0b41-\\u0b43\\u0b4d\\u0b56\\u0b82\\u0bc0\\u0bcd\\u0c3e-\\u0c40\\u0c46-\\u0c48\\u0c4a-\\u0c4d\\u0c55\\u0c56\\u0cbc\\u0cbf\\u0cc6\\u0ccc\\u0ccd\\u0ce2\\u0ce3\\u0d41-\\u0d43\\u0d4d\\u0dca\\u0dd2-\\u0dd4\\u0dd6\\u0e31\\u0e34-\\u0e3a\\u0e47-\\u0e4e\\u0eb1\\u0eb4-\\u0eb9\\u0ebb\\u0ebc\\u0ec8-\\u0ecd\\u0f18\\u0f19\\u0f35\\u0f37\\u0f39\\u0f71-\\u0f7e\\u0f80-\\u0f84\\u0f86\\u0f87\\u0f90-\\u0f97\\u0f99-\\u0fbc\\u0fc6\\u102d-\\u1030\\u1032\\u1036\\u1037\\u1039\\u1058\\u1059\\u135f\\u1712-\\u1714\\u1732-\\u1734\\u1752\\u1753\\u1772\\u1773\\u17b7-\\u17bd\\u17c6\\u17c9-\\u17d3\\u17dd\\u180b-\\u180d\\u18a9\\u1920-\\u1922\\u1927\\u1928\\u1932\\u1939-\\u193b\\u1a17\\u1a18\\u1b00-\\u1b03\\u1b34\\u1b36-\\u1b3a\\u1b3c\\u1b42\\u1b6b-\\u1b73\\u1dc0-\\u1dca\\u1dfe\\u1dff\\u20d0-\\u20dc\\u20e1\\u20e5-\\u20ef\\u302a-\\u302f\\u3099\\u309a\\ua806\\ua80b\\ua825\\ua826\\ufb1e\\ufe00-\\ufe0f\\ufe20-\\ufe23",
Ps: "\\u0028\\u005b\\u007b\\u0f3a\\u0f3c\\u169b\\u201a\\u201e\\u2045\\u207d\\u208d\\u2329\\u2768\\u276a\\u276c\\u276e\\u2770\\u2772\\u2774\\u27c5\\u27e6\\u27e8\\u27ea\\u2983\\u2985\\u2987\\u2989\\u298b\\u298d\\u298f\\u2991\\u2993\\u2995\\u2997\\u29d8\\u29da\\u29fc\\u3008\\u300a\\u300c\\u300e\\u3010\\u3014\\u3016\\u3018\\u301a\\u301d\\ufd3e\\ufe17\\ufe35\\ufe37\\ufe39\\ufe3b\\ufe3d\\ufe3f\\ufe41\\ufe43\\ufe47\\ufe59\\ufe5b\\ufe5d\\uff08\\uff3b\\uff5b\\uff5f\\uff62",
Cc: "\\u0000-\\u001f\\u007f-\\u009f",
Cf: "\\u00ad\\u0600-\\u0603\\u06dd\\u070f\\u17b4\\u17b5\\u200b-\\u200f\\u202a-\\u202e\\u2060-\\u2063\\u206a-\\u206f\\ufeff\\ufff9-\\ufffb",
Ll: "\\u0061-\\u007a\\u00aa\\u00b5\\u00ba\\u00df-\\u00f6\\u00f8-\\u00ff\\u0101\\u0103\\u0105\\u0107\\u0109\\u010b\\u010d\\u010f\\u0111\\u0113\\u0115\\u0117\\u0119\\u011b\\u011d\\u011f\\u0121\\u0123\\u0125\\u0127\\u0129\\u012b\\u012d\\u012f\\u0131\\u0133\\u0135\\u0137\\u0138\\u013a\\u013c\\u013e\\u0140\\u0142\\u0144\\u0146\\u0148\\u0149\\u014b\\u014d\\u014f\\u0151\\u0153\\u0155\\u0157\\u0159\\u015b\\u015d\\u015f\\u0161\\u0163\\u0165\\u0167\\u0169\\u016b\\u016d\\u016f\\u0171\\u0173\\u0175\\u0177\\u017a\\u017c\\u017e-\\u0180\\u0183\\u0185\\u0188\\u018c\\u018d\\u0192\\u0195\\u0199-\\u019b\\u019e\\u01a1\\u01a3\\u01a5\\u01a8\\u01aa\\u01ab\\u01ad\\u01b0\\u01b4\\u01b6\\u01b9\\u01ba\\u01bd-\\u01bf\\u01c6\\u01c9\\u01cc\\u01ce\\u01d0\\u01d2\\u01d4\\u01d6\\u01d8\\u01da\\u01dc\\u01dd\\u01df\\u01e1\\u01e3\\u01e5\\u01e7\\u01e9\\u01eb\\u01ed\\u01ef\\u01f0\\u01f3\\u01f5\\u01f9\\u01fb\\u01fd\\u01ff\\u0201\\u0203\\u0205\\u0207\\u0209\\u020b\\u020d\\u020f\\u0211\\u0213\\u0215\\u0217\\u0219\\u021b\\u021d\\u021f\\u0221\\u0223\\u0225\\u0227\\u0229\\u022b\\u022d\\u022f\\u0231\\u0233-\\u0239\\u023c\\u023f\\u0240\\u0242\\u0247\\u0249\\u024b\\u024d\\u024f-\\u0293\\u0295-\\u02af\\u037b-\\u037d\\u0390\\u03ac-\\u03ce\\u03d0\\u03d1\\u03d5-\\u03d7\\u03d9\\u03db\\u03dd\\u03df\\u03e1\\u03e3\\u03e5\\u03e7\\u03e9\\u03eb\\u03ed\\u03ef-\\u03f3\\u03f5\\u03f8\\u03fb\\u03fc\\u0430-\\u045f\\u0461\\u0463\\u0465\\u0467\\u0469\\u046b\\u046d\\u046f\\u0471\\u0473\\u0475\\u0477\\u0479\\u047b\\u047d\\u047f\\u0481\\u048b\\u048d\\u048f\\u0491\\u0493\\u0495\\u0497\\u0499\\u049b\\u049d\\u049f\\u04a1\\u04a3\\u04a5\\u04a7\\u04a9\\u04ab\\u04ad\\u04af\\u04b1\\u04b3\\u04b5\\u04b7\\u04b9\\u04bb\\u04bd\\u04bf\\u04c2\\u04c4\\u04c6\\u04c8\\u04ca\\u04cc\\u04ce\\u04cf\\u04d1\\u04d3\\u04d5\\u04d7\\u04d9\\u04db\\u04dd\\u04df\\u04e1\\u04e3\\u04e5\\u04e7\\u04e9\\u04eb\\u04ed\\u04ef\\u04f1\\u04f3\\u04f5\\u04f7\\u04f9\\u04fb\\u04fd\\u04ff\\u0501\\u0503\\u0505\\u0507\\u0509\\u050b\\u050d\\u050f\\u0511\\u0513\\u0561-\\u0587\\u1d00-\\u1d2b\\u1d62-\\u1d77\\u1d79-\\u1d9a\\u1e01\\u1e03\\u1e05\\u1e07\\u1e09\\u1e0b\\u1e0d\\u1e0f\\u1e11\\u1e13\\u1e15\\u1e17\\u1e19\\u1e1b\\u1e1d\\u1e1f\\u1e21\\u1e23\\u1e25\\u1e27\\u1e29\\u1e2b\\u1e2d\\u1e2f\\u1e31\\u1e33\\u1e35\\u1e37\\u1e39\\u1e3b\\u1e3d\\u1e3f\\u1e41\\u1e43\\u1e45\\u1e47\\u1e49\\u1e4b\\u1e4d\\u1e4f\\u1e51\\u1e53\\u1e55\\u1e57\\u1e59\\u1e5b\\u1e5d\\u1e5f\\u1e61\\u1e63\\u1e65\\u1e67\\u1e69\\u1e6b\\u1e6d\\u1e6f\\u1e71\\u1e73\\u1e75\\u1e77\\u1e79\\u1e7b\\u1e7d\\u1e7f\\u1e81\\u1e83\\u1e85\\u1e87\\u1e89\\u1e8b\\u1e8d\\u1e8f\\u1e91\\u1e93\\u1e95-\\u1e9b\\u1ea1\\u1ea3\\u1ea5\\u1ea7\\u1ea9\\u1eab\\u1ead\\u1eaf\\u1eb1\\u1eb3\\u1eb5\\u1eb7\\u1eb9\\u1ebb\\u1ebd\\u1ebf\\u1ec1\\u1ec3\\u1ec5\\u1ec7\\u1ec9\\u1ecb\\u1ecd\\u1ecf\\u1ed1\\u1ed3\\u1ed5\\u1ed7\\u1ed9\\u1edb\\u1edd\\u1edf\\u1ee1\\u1ee3\\u1ee5\\u1ee7\\u1ee9\\u1eeb\\u1eed\\u1eef\\u1ef1\\u1ef3\\u1ef5\\u1ef7\\u1ef9\\u1f00-\\u1f07\\u1f10-\\u1f15\\u1f20-\\u1f27\\u1f30-\\u1f37\\u1f40-\\u1f45\\u1f50-\\u1f57\\u1f60-\\u1f67\\u1f70-\\u1f7d\\u1f80-\\u1f87\\u1f90-\\u1f97\\u1fa0-\\u1fa7\\u1fb0-\\u1fb4\\u1fb6\\u1fb7\\u1fbe\\u1fc2-\\u1fc4\\u1fc6\\u1fc7\\u1fd0-\\u1fd3\\u1fd6\\u1fd7\\u1fe0-\\u1fe7\\u1ff2-\\u1ff4\\u1ff6\\u1ff7\\u2071\\u207f\\u210a\\u210e\\u210f\\u2113\\u212f\\u2134\\u2139\\u213c\\u213d\\u2146-\\u2149\\u214e\\u2184\\u2c30-\\u2c5e\\u2c61\\u2c65\\u2c66\\u2c68\\u2c6a\\u2c6c\\u2c74\\u2c76\\u2c77\\u2c81\\u2c83\\u2c85\\u2c87\\u2c89\\u2c8b\\u2c8d\\u2c8f\\u2c91\\u2c93\\u2c95\\u2c97\\u2c99\\u2c9b\\u2c9d\\u2c9f\\u2ca1\\u2ca3\\u2ca5\\u2ca7\\u2ca9\\u2cab\\u2cad\\u2caf\\u2cb1\\u2cb3\\u2cb5\\u2cb7\\u2cb9\\u2cbb\\u2cbd\\u2cbf\\u2cc1\\u2cc3\\u2cc5\\u2cc7\\u2cc9\\u2ccb\\u2ccd\\u2ccf\\u2cd1\\u2cd3\\u2cd5\\u2cd7\\u2cd9\\u2cdb\\u2cdd\\u2cdf\\u2ce1\\u2ce3\\u2ce4\\u2d00-\\u2d25\\ufb00-\\ufb06\\ufb13-\\ufb17\\uff41-\\uff5a",
Lo: "\\u01bb\\u01c0-\\u01c3\\u0294\\u05d0-\\u05ea\\u05f0-\\u05f2\\u0621-\\u063a\\u0641-\\u064a\\u066e\\u066f\\u0671-\\u06d3\\u06d5\\u06ee\\u06ef\\u06fa-\\u06fc\\u06ff\\u0710\\u0712-\\u072f\\u074d-\\u076d\\u0780-\\u07a5\\u07b1\\u07ca-\\u07ea\\u0904-\\u0939\\u093d\\u0950\\u0958-\\u0961\\u097b-\\u097f\\u0985-\\u098c\\u098f\\u0990\\u0993-\\u09a8\\u09aa-\\u09b0\\u09b2\\u09b6-\\u09b9\\u09bd\\u09ce\\u09dc\\u09dd\\u09df-\\u09e1\\u09f0\\u09f1\\u0a05-\\u0a0a\\u0a0f\\u0a10\\u0a13-\\u0a28\\u0a2a-\\u0a30\\u0a32\\u0a33\\u0a35\\u0a36\\u0a38\\u0a39\\u0a59-\\u0a5c\\u0a5e\\u0a72-\\u0a74\\u0a85-\\u0a8d\\u0a8f-\\u0a91\\u0a93-\\u0aa8\\u0aaa-\\u0ab0\\u0ab2\\u0ab3\\u0ab5-\\u0ab9\\u0abd\\u0ad0\\u0ae0\\u0ae1\\u0b05-\\u0b0c\\u0b0f\\u0b10\\u0b13-\\u0b28\\u0b2a-\\u0b30\\u0b32\\u0b33\\u0b35-\\u0b39\\u0b3d\\u0b5c\\u0b5d\\u0b5f-\\u0b61\\u0b71\\u0b83\\u0b85-\\u0b8a\\u0b8e-\\u0b90\\u0b92-\\u0b95\\u0b99\\u0b9a\\u0b9c\\u0b9e\\u0b9f\\u0ba3\\u0ba4\\u0ba8-\\u0baa\\u0bae-\\u0bb9\\u0c05-\\u0c0c\\u0c0e-\\u0c10\\u0c12-\\u0c28\\u0c2a-\\u0c33\\u0c35-\\u0c39\\u0c60\\u0c61\\u0c85-\\u0c8c\\u0c8e-\\u0c90\\u0c92-\\u0ca8\\u0caa-\\u0cb3\\u0cb5-\\u0cb9\\u0cbd\\u0cde\\u0ce0\\u0ce1\\u0d05-\\u0d0c\\u0d0e-\\u0d10\\u0d12-\\u0d28\\u0d2a-\\u0d39\\u0d60\\u0d61\\u0d85-\\u0d96\\u0d9a-\\u0db1\\u0db3-\\u0dbb\\u0dbd\\u0dc0-\\u0dc6\\u0e01-\\u0e30\\u0e32\\u0e33\\u0e40-\\u0e45\\u0e81\\u0e82\\u0e84\\u0e87\\u0e88\\u0e8a\\u0e8d\\u0e94-\\u0e97\\u0e99-\\u0e9f\\u0ea1-\\u0ea3\\u0ea5\\u0ea7\\u0eaa\\u0eab\\u0ead-\\u0eb0\\u0eb2\\u0eb3\\u0ebd\\u0ec0-\\u0ec4\\u0edc\\u0edd\\u0f00\\u0f40-\\u0f47\\u0f49-\\u0f6a\\u0f88-\\u0f8b\\u1000-\\u1021\\u1023-\\u1027\\u1029\\u102a\\u1050-\\u1055\\u10d0-\\u10fa\\u1100-\\u1159\\u115f-\\u11a2\\u11a8-\\u11f9\\u1200-\\u1248\\u124a-\\u124d\\u1250-\\u1256\\u1258\\u125a-\\u125d\\u1260-\\u1288\\u128a-\\u128d\\u1290-\\u12b0\\u12b2-\\u12b5\\u12b8-\\u12be\\u12c0\\u12c2-\\u12c5\\u12c8-\\u12d6\\u12d8-\\u1310\\u1312-\\u1315\\u1318-\\u135a\\u1380-\\u138f\\u13a0-\\u13f4\\u1401-\\u166c\\u166f-\\u1676\\u1681-\\u169a\\u16a0-\\u16ea\\u1700-\\u170c\\u170e-\\u1711\\u1720-\\u1731\\u1740-\\u1751\\u1760-\\u176c\\u176e-\\u1770\\u1780-\\u17b3\\u17dc\\u1820-\\u1842\\u1844-\\u1877\\u1880-\\u18a8\\u1900-\\u191c\\u1950-\\u196d\\u1970-\\u1974\\u1980-\\u19a9\\u19c1-\\u19c7\\u1a00-\\u1a16\\u1b05-\\u1b33\\u1b45-\\u1b4b\\u2135-\\u2138\\u2d30-\\u2d65\\u2d80-\\u2d96\\u2da0-\\u2da6\\u2da8-\\u2dae\\u2db0-\\u2db6\\u2db8-\\u2dbe\\u2dc0-\\u2dc6\\u2dc8-\\u2dce\\u2dd0-\\u2dd6\\u2dd8-\\u2dde\\u3006\\u303c\\u3041-\\u3096\\u309f\\u30a1-\\u30fa\\u30ff\\u3105-\\u312c\\u3131-\\u318e\\u31a0-\\u31b7\\u31f0-\\u31ff\\u3400-\\u4db5\\u4db5\\u4e00-\\u9faf\\u9fbb\\ua000-\\ua014\\ua016-\\ua48c\\ua800\\ua801\\ua803-\\ua805\\ua807-\\ua80a\\ua80c-\\ua822\\ua840-\\ua873\\uac00\\ud7a3\\uf900-\\ufa2d\\ufa30-\\ufa6a\\ufa70-\\ufad9\\ufb1d\\ufb1f-\\ufb28\\ufb2a-\\ufb36\\ufb38-\\ufb3c\\ufb3e\\ufb40\\ufb41\\ufb43\\ufb44\\ufb46-\\ufbb1\\ufbd3-\\ufd3d\\ufd50-\\ufd8f\\ufd92-\\ufdc7\\ufdf0-\\ufdfb\\ufe70-\\ufe74\\ufe76-\\ufefc\\uff66-\\uff6f\\uff71-\\uff9d\\uffa0-\\uffbe\\uffc2-\\uffc7\\uffca-\\uffcf\\uffd2-\\uffd7\\uffda-\\uffdc",
Co: "\\ue000\\uf8ff",
Nd: "\\u0030-\\u0039\\u0660-\\u0669\\u06f0-\\u06f9\\u07c0-\\u07c9\\u0966-\\u096f\\u09e6-\\u09ef\\u0a66-\\u0a6f\\u0ae6-\\u0aef\\u0b66-\\u0b6f\\u0be6-\\u0bef\\u0c66-\\u0c6f\\u0ce6-\\u0cef\\u0d66-\\u0d6f\\u0e50-\\u0e59\\u0ed0-\\u0ed9\\u0f20-\\u0f29\\u1040-\\u1049\\u17e0-\\u17e9\\u1810-\\u1819\\u1946-\\u194f\\u19d0-\\u19d9\\u1b50-\\u1b59\\uff10-\\uff19",
Lt: "\\u01c5\\u01c8\\u01cb\\u01f2\\u1f88-\\u1f8f\\u1f98-\\u1f9f\\u1fa8-\\u1faf\\u1fbc\\u1fcc\\u1ffc",
Lu: "\\u0041-\\u005a\\u00c0-\\u00d6\\u00d8-\\u00de\\u0100\\u0102\\u0104\\u0106\\u0108\\u010a\\u010c\\u010e\\u0110\\u0112\\u0114\\u0116\\u0118\\u011a\\u011c\\u011e\\u0120\\u0122\\u0124\\u0126\\u0128\\u012a\\u012c\\u012e\\u0130\\u0132\\u0134\\u0136\\u0139\\u013b\\u013d\\u013f\\u0141\\u0143\\u0145\\u0147\\u014a\\u014c\\u014e\\u0150\\u0152\\u0154\\u0156\\u0158\\u015a\\u015c\\u015e\\u0160\\u0162\\u0164\\u0166\\u0168\\u016a\\u016c\\u016e\\u0170\\u0172\\u0174\\u0176\\u0178\\u0179\\u017b\\u017d\\u0181\\u0182\\u0184\\u0186\\u0187\\u0189-\\u018b\\u018e-\\u0191\\u0193\\u0194\\u0196-\\u0198\\u019c\\u019d\\u019f\\u01a0\\u01a2\\u01a4\\u01a6\\u01a7\\u01a9\\u01ac\\u01ae\\u01af\\u01b1-\\u01b3\\u01b5\\u01b7\\u01b8\\u01bc\\u01c4\\u01c7\\u01ca\\u01cd\\u01cf\\u01d1\\u01d3\\u01d5\\u01d7\\u01d9\\u01db\\u01de\\u01e0\\u01e2\\u01e4\\u01e6\\u01e8\\u01ea\\u01ec\\u01ee\\u01f1\\u01f4\\u01f6-\\u01f8\\u01fa\\u01fc\\u01fe\\u0200\\u0202\\u0204\\u0206\\u0208\\u020a\\u020c\\u020e\\u0210\\u0212\\u0214\\u0216\\u0218\\u021a\\u021c\\u021e\\u0220\\u0222\\u0224\\u0226\\u0228\\u022a\\u022c\\u022e\\u0230\\u0232\\u023a\\u023b\\u023d\\u023e\\u0241\\u0243-\\u0246\\u0248\\u024a\\u024c\\u024e\\u0386\\u0388-\\u038a\\u038c\\u038e\\u038f\\u0391-\\u03a1\\u03a3-\\u03ab\\u03d2-\\u03d4\\u03d8\\u03da\\u03dc\\u03de\\u03e0\\u03e2\\u03e4\\u03e6\\u03e8\\u03ea\\u03ec\\u03ee\\u03f4\\u03f7\\u03f9\\u03fa\\u03fd-\\u042f\\u0460\\u0462\\u0464\\u0466\\u0468\\u046a\\u046c\\u046e\\u0470\\u0472\\u0474\\u0476\\u0478\\u047a\\u047c\\u047e\\u0480\\u048a\\u048c\\u048e\\u0490\\u0492\\u0494\\u0496\\u0498\\u049a\\u049c\\u049e\\u04a0\\u04a2\\u04a4\\u04a6\\u04a8\\u04aa\\u04ac\\u04ae\\u04b0\\u04b2\\u04b4\\u04b6\\u04b8\\u04ba\\u04bc\\u04be\\u04c0\\u04c1\\u04c3\\u04c5\\u04c7\\u04c9\\u04cb\\u04cd\\u04d0\\u04d2\\u04d4\\u04d6\\u04d8\\u04da\\u04dc\\u04de\\u04e0\\u04e2\\u04e4\\u04e6\\u04e8\\u04ea\\u04ec\\u04ee\\u04f0\\u04f2\\u04f4\\u04f6\\u04f8\\u04fa\\u04fc\\u04fe\\u0500\\u0502\\u0504\\u0506\\u0508\\u050a\\u050c\\u050e\\u0510\\u0512\\u0531-\\u0556\\u10a0-\\u10c5\\u1e00\\u1e02\\u1e04\\u1e06\\u1e08\\u1e0a\\u1e0c\\u1e0e\\u1e10\\u1e12\\u1e14\\u1e16\\u1e18\\u1e1a\\u1e1c\\u1e1e\\u1e20\\u1e22\\u1e24\\u1e26\\u1e28\\u1e2a\\u1e2c\\u1e2e\\u1e30\\u1e32\\u1e34\\u1e36\\u1e38\\u1e3a\\u1e3c\\u1e3e\\u1e40\\u1e42\\u1e44\\u1e46\\u1e48\\u1e4a\\u1e4c\\u1e4e\\u1e50\\u1e52\\u1e54\\u1e56\\u1e58\\u1e5a\\u1e5c\\u1e5e\\u1e60\\u1e62\\u1e64\\u1e66\\u1e68\\u1e6a\\u1e6c\\u1e6e\\u1e70\\u1e72\\u1e74\\u1e76\\u1e78\\u1e7a\\u1e7c\\u1e7e\\u1e80\\u1e82\\u1e84\\u1e86\\u1e88\\u1e8a\\u1e8c\\u1e8e\\u1e90\\u1e92\\u1e94\\u1ea0\\u1ea2\\u1ea4\\u1ea6\\u1ea8\\u1eaa\\u1eac\\u1eae\\u1eb0\\u1eb2\\u1eb4\\u1eb6\\u1eb8\\u1eba\\u1ebc\\u1ebe\\u1ec0\\u1ec2\\u1ec4\\u1ec6\\u1ec8\\u1eca\\u1ecc\\u1ece\\u1ed0\\u1ed2\\u1ed4\\u1ed6\\u1ed8\\u1eda\\u1edc\\u1ede\\u1ee0\\u1ee2\\u1ee4\\u1ee6\\u1ee8\\u1eea\\u1eec\\u1eee\\u1ef0\\u1ef2\\u1ef4\\u1ef6\\u1ef8\\u1f08-\\u1f0f\\u1f18-\\u1f1d\\u1f28-\\u1f2f\\u1f38-\\u1f3f\\u1f48-\\u1f4d\\u1f59\\u1f5b\\u1f5d\\u1f5f\\u1f68-\\u1f6f\\u1fb8-\\u1fbb\\u1fc8-\\u1fcb\\u1fd8-\\u1fdb\\u1fe8-\\u1fec\\u1ff8-\\u1ffb\\u2102\\u2107\\u210b-\\u210d\\u2110-\\u2112\\u2115\\u2119-\\u211d\\u2124\\u2126\\u2128\\u212a-\\u212d\\u2130-\\u2133\\u213e\\u213f\\u2145\\u2183\\u2c00-\\u2c2e\\u2c60\\u2c62-\\u2c64\\u2c67\\u2c69\\u2c6b\\u2c75\\u2c80\\u2c82\\u2c84\\u2c86\\u2c88\\u2c8a\\u2c8c\\u2c8e\\u2c90\\u2c92\\u2c94\\u2c96\\u2c98\\u2c9a\\u2c9c\\u2c9e\\u2ca0\\u2ca2\\u2ca4\\u2ca6\\u2ca8\\u2caa\\u2cac\\u2cae\\u2cb0\\u2cb2\\u2cb4\\u2cb6\\u2cb8\\u2cba\\u2cbc\\u2cbe\\u2cc0\\u2cc2\\u2cc4\\u2cc6\\u2cc8\\u2cca\\u2ccc\\u2cce\\u2cd0\\u2cd2\\u2cd4\\u2cd6\\u2cd8\\u2cda\\u2cdc\\u2cde\\u2ce0\\u2ce2\\uff21-\\uff3a",
Cs: "\\ud800\\udb7f\\udb80\\udbff\\udc00\\udfff",
Zl: "\\u2028",
Nl: "\\u16ee-\\u16f0\\u2160-\\u2182\\u3007\\u3021-\\u3029\\u3038-\\u303a",
Zp: "\\u2029",
No: "\\u00b2\\u00b3\\u00b9\\u00bc-\\u00be\\u09f4-\\u09f9\\u0bf0-\\u0bf2\\u0f2a-\\u0f33\\u1369-\\u137c\\u17f0-\\u17f9\\u2070\\u2074-\\u2079\\u2080-\\u2089\\u2153-\\u215f\\u2460-\\u249b\\u24ea-\\u24ff\\u2776-\\u2793\\u2cfd\\u3192-\\u3195\\u3220-\\u3229\\u3251-\\u325f\\u3280-\\u3289\\u32b1-\\u32bf",
Zs: "\\u0020\\u00a0\\u1680\\u180e\\u2000-\\u200a\\u202f\\u205f\\u3000",
Sc: "\\u0024\\u00a2-\\u00a5\\u060b\\u09f2\\u09f3\\u0af1\\u0bf9\\u0e3f\\u17db\\u20a0-\\u20b5\\ufdfc\\ufe69\\uff04\\uffe0\\uffe1\\uffe5\\uffe6",
Pc: "\\u005f\\u203f\\u2040\\u2054\\ufe33\\ufe34\\ufe4d-\\ufe4f\\uff3f",
Pd: "\\u002d\\u058a\\u1806\\u2010-\\u2015\\u2e17\\u301c\\u3030\\u30a0\\ufe31\\ufe32\\ufe58\\ufe63\\uff0d",
Pe: "\\u0029\\u005d\\u007d\\u0f3b\\u0f3d\\u169c\\u2046\\u207e\\u208e\\u232a\\u2769\\u276b\\u276d\\u276f\\u2771\\u2773\\u2775\\u27c6\\u27e7\\u27e9\\u27eb\\u2984\\u2986\\u2988\\u298a\\u298c\\u298e\\u2990\\u2992\\u2994\\u2996\\u2998\\u29d9\\u29db\\u29fd\\u3009\\u300b\\u300d\\u300f\\u3011\\u3015\\u3017\\u3019\\u301b\\u301e\\u301f\\ufd3f\\ufe18\\ufe36\\ufe38\\ufe3a\\ufe3c\\ufe3e\\ufe40\\ufe42\\ufe44\\ufe48\\ufe5a\\ufe5c\\ufe5e\\uff09\\uff3d\\uff5d\\uff60\\uff63",
Pf: "\\u00bb\\u2019\\u201d\\u203a\\u2e03\\u2e05\\u2e0a\\u2e0d\\u2e1d",
Me: "\\u0488\\u0489\\u06de\\u20dd-\\u20e0\\u20e2-\\u20e4",
Mc: "\\u0903\\u093e-\\u0940\\u0949-\\u094c\\u0982\\u0983\\u09be-\\u09c0\\u09c7\\u09c8\\u09cb\\u09cc\\u09d7\\u0a03\\u0a3e-\\u0a40\\u0a83\\u0abe-\\u0ac0\\u0ac9\\u0acb\\u0acc\\u0b02\\u0b03\\u0b3e\\u0b40\\u0b47\\u0b48\\u0b4b\\u0b4c\\u0b57\\u0bbe\\u0bbf\\u0bc1\\u0bc2\\u0bc6-\\u0bc8\\u0bca-\\u0bcc\\u0bd7\\u0c01-\\u0c03\\u0c41-\\u0c44\\u0c82\\u0c83\\u0cbe\\u0cc0-\\u0cc4\\u0cc7\\u0cc8\\u0cca\\u0ccb\\u0cd5\\u0cd6\\u0d02\\u0d03\\u0d3e-\\u0d40\\u0d46-\\u0d48\\u0d4a-\\u0d4c\\u0d57\\u0d82\\u0d83\\u0dcf-\\u0dd1\\u0dd8-\\u0ddf\\u0df2\\u0df3\\u0f3e\\u0f3f\\u0f7f\\u102c\\u1031\\u1038\\u1056\\u1057\\u17b6\\u17be-\\u17c5\\u17c7\\u17c8\\u1923-\\u1926\\u1929-\\u192b\\u1930\\u1931\\u1933-\\u1938\\u19b0-\\u19c0\\u19c8\\u19c9\\u1a19-\\u1a1b\\u1b04\\u1b35\\u1b3b\\u1b3d-\\u1b41\\u1b43\\u1b44\\ua802\\ua823\\ua824\\ua827",
L: undefined,
M: undefined,
Z: undefined,
S: undefined,
N: undefined,
P: undefined,
C: undefined,
};
u.L = u.Ll + u.Lo + u.Lt + u.Lu;
u.M = u.Mc + u.Me + u.Mn;
u.Z = u.Zl + u.Zp + u.Zs;
u.S = u.Sc + u.Sk + u.Sm + u.So;
u.N = u.Nd + u.Nl + u.No;
u.P = u.Pc + u.Pd + u.Pe + u.Pf + u.Pi + u.Po;
u.C = u.Cc + u.Cf + u.Co + u.Cs;
var w = "\\w" + u.L;
var d = u.N;
```

Thanks to mgibsonbr, [his list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933546/1540350) helped me to get all the unicode ranges. (Check the script)

As you can see, it contains a huge global variable that handles unicode codes for all `\p` extensions, a variable for the `\w` parameter and a variable for the `\d` parameter. It's already double escaped, because the validation controls of ASP.NET store the client sided regular expression inside a variable, hence it needs to be double escaped. For more information about the unicode maps: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Looking to the produced client sided ASP.NET code we can see a regular expression validator produces some like these:

```
ContentPlaceHolder1_RegularExpressionValidator1.validationexpression = "^[\\p{L}]{0,32}$";
```

So I added something to the Render method of the master site:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    this.CacheControl.RenderHeader(this.Page);
    using (HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter()))
    {
        base.Render(htmlwriter);
        string html = htmlwriter.InnerWriter.ToString();

        /* To support unicode \w, \d and \p{X} variables inside of asp:RegularExpressionValidator controls on client side.
        * This can actually only work when your website reffers to the UnicodeRegex.js that includes 
        * the initialisation of the global u and w variable.
        * This also only work as long as \w and \p{X} are inside of corner brackets [] in your expressions.
        * Do not use \W, \D and \P{X} with it, instead negate it with ^.
        */
        html = Regex.Replace(html, @"(?<=\.validationexpression = "".*?)\\\\w(?=.*?(?<!\\)"")", "\" + w + \"");
        html = Regex.Replace(html, @"(?<=\.validationexpression = "".*?)\\\\d(?=.*?(?<!\\)"")", "\" + d + \"");
        html = Regex.Replace(html, @"(?<=\.validationexpression = "".*?)\\\\p\{([a-zA-Z]{1,2})\}(?=.*?(?<!\\)"")", "\" + u.$1 + \"");

        writer.Write(html);
    }
}
```

When looking on the result HTML, it will hook the variable from our JS into the `validationexpression` variable:

```
ContentPlaceHolder1_RegularExpressionValidator1.validationexpression = "^[" + u.L + "]{0,32}$";
```

As you can see on the comments I made in the `Render` function, this trick / hack will restrict your usage of possibilities in the `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` though. So you cannot use `\W`, `\D` and `\P{X}` as well as you have to place `\w`, `\d` and `\p{X}` between corner brackets `[]`, always.

I hope anybody will come with a better solution, but for now, it works.